# jQuery Selector -- Children / Sub Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with some HTML content inside `<div id="content-text">` which (unfortunately) doesn't have any ids or classes in it's sub elements.  Like...

```
<div id="content-text">
  <p>
    <ol>
      <li>first thing</li>
      <li>second thing</li>
    </ol>
  </p>
  etc......
</div>
```

I need to be able to select the HTML from elements like "the 3rd `<p>` tag" or "the 5th `<li>` tag" **within** the `<div id="content-text">` using jQuery.  I've tried things like `$("#content-text").children("p:eq(5)").eq(4).html();`, but I keep getting a result of null.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:nth-of-type`:

```
$('#content-text > p:nth-of-type(5)') // fifth p that is a direct child of #content-text
$('#content-text li:nth-of-type(3)') // third li, not direct child
```

Comment: This is strange.  When I use `$("#content-text p:nth-of-type(4)").html();`, I'm getting the 4th `<p>` of a `<table>` in the `<div>`.  But when I use `$("#content-text p:nth-of-type(3)").html();`, the proper `<p>` is selected.  Thoughts?